# Significato di "liscio come un'asse"

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Solo allora il vecchio spiegò che di bestie dalla stalla non gliene mancava neanche una, ma che si trattava di Mario Bernasca che nella notte gli era scappato da servitore portandogli via della roba. Tutti, specie i piú giovani, si misero a dirne di Mario come se Mario non avesse fatto che rubare da quando era nato, finché uno gli domandò cosa gli aveva poi rubato. Il vecchio s’imbrogliò e disse che non poteva ancora saperlo di preciso perché non s’era fidato a perder tempo a fare il conto della roba. Allora se la pigliarono con lui e gliene dissero d’ogni colore, anche se poteva essere il nonno di tutti. Finí lí, e da quelle parti Mario Bernasca non l’ha piú rivisto nessuno. Però si venne a sapere che quando scappò era **liscio come un’asse**: il giorno prima il suo padrone l’aveva mandato al forno a Manera e mentre il pane cuoceva il figlio del panettiere l’aveva piumato giocandogli insieme al nove sulla pietra del forno.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato dell'espressione "liscio come un'asse"? Si tratta di un modo di dire? Da dove proviene? Non ho trovato questa espressione in nessun dizionario, neanche nel dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli, ma una cerca su Google mi ha fatto vedere alcuni esempi di uso in altri contesti.

Comment: Il significato di _liscio come un asse_ viene spiegato nella frase successiva: il giorno prima il suo padrone l'aveva mandato al forno e mentre il pane cuoceva il figlio del panettiere lo aveva piumato (o meglio spiumato, come un pollo, portandogli via i soldi) giocando con lui al nove ([nove, gioco di carte](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nove_(gioco_di_carte))) sulla pietra del forno.

Comment: Quindi in questo contesto significa completamente squattrinato, senza una lira. In altri contesti ho trovato che liscio come un asse può anche significare estremamente magro, ma questo non sembra il nostro caso.

Comment: @abarisone:  O forse il senso in generale sarebbe "totalmente piatto" (come un'asse, che è rettilinea)? Qui il senso sarebbe  più o meno che le tasche di Mario Bernasca erano totalmente piatte poiché non avevano un soldo.

Comment: Potrebbe anche essere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato di ***liscio come un'asse*** viene spiegato nella frase successiva: il giorno prima il suo padrone l'aveva mandato al forno e mentre il pane cuoceva il figlio del panettiere lo aveva piumato (o meglio spiumato, come un pollo, portandogli via i soldi) giocando con lui al nove ([nove, gioco di carte](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nove_(gioco_di_carte))) sulla pietra del forno.

Quindi in questo contesto significa completamente squattrinato, senza una lira.

Come fa giustamente notare @Charo, forse il senso in generale sarebbe "totalmente piatto", come un'asse piallata. Qui il senso sarebbe più o meno che le tasche di Mario Bernasca erano totalmente piatte poiché non avevano un soldo al loro interno.

In altri contesti ho trovato che liscio come un'asse può anche significare estremamente magro, ma questo non sembra il nostro caso.

Comment: Non è un'asse "piallata"?

Comment: Giusto, ho usato asse [al maschile invece che al femminile](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/asse-maschile-o-femminile_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)...

Comment: Io stessa non avevo chiara la differenza tra asse maschile e asse femminile: consultando il dizionario l'ho appena scoperta.

Comment: Immagino si tratti di una variante di ["liscio come un biliardo"](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/L/liscio.shtml).